# C++ :: Is there anything wrong with this code? It compiles fine but people tell me there will be a memory leak

Tags: c++

Assume that there is a user defined class `Student`. Consider the following two functions:

```
Student someFunc1() {
    return *(new Student("John",25)); 
}

Student& someFunc2() {
    return *(new Student("John",25)); 
}
```

Without going into the details as to why they have been implemented the way they have been, are they both correct? Somebody told me that there would be a memory leak but how come?

Comment: The first one has an irrecoverable memory leak. The second one has a potential memory leak but the caller can still de-allocate. I suggest spending some time learning C++ from some good books. It will take you 300 years to learn one trivial question at a time.

Comment: Why don't you try it? Smells like homework to me...

Comment: Please explain what is going on in the second function. Is it equivalent to returning a pointer?

Comment: Well, I did and finished my homework just fine. I just started thinking beyond it. If you're going to chastise me for that, then I'll stop learning C++ and learn Java instead. That will be bad, bad for C++.

Comment: Which part is unclear to you? Which parts are clear? If you tried to run that code, what did you find out?

Comment: No big loss when you are so easily turned off of C++. As @juanchopanza mentioned getting a book is the way to go. Otherwise you'll always have misconceptions how C++ works and as a result will create bad code.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in), it should answer alot of your future questions about pointers/references.

Comment: @AnonymousAndy: Manual resource management can be complex and error prone. I suggest you stop using `new` until you know the language better. There are reasons why we have `std::string` and containers like `std::vector`, they manage memory and hide this complexity so you can get on with your actual programming logic.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there certainly is something wrong.

`someFunc1()` will definitely cause a memory leak, because the memory address of the allocated object is lost.

`someFunc2()` will cause a risk for a memory leak, because the user of the function has to remember to delete the returned object with a weird syntax (`delete &object`).

Neither of them is good C++. A correct version would be:

```
Student someFunc3() {
    return Student("John",25); 
}
```

Comment: @AnonymousAndy The second function returns a _reference_ (`&` syntax) to the newly allocated object. It's almost equivalent to returning a pointer, except that the variable is not a memory address and without the pointer dereference syntax hassle, and `nullptr` is not possible using references.

Answer (score 3):

The first function allocates an object, that dereferences it and returns.  By default, return does a *copy* of object.  Thus the originally allocated object still exists, but is not accessible anymore.  Which is a memory leak by definition.

In the second case, however, the reference to the allocated object is returned rather than a copy.  This way, the caller may still take an address of the object and delete it.

Comment: An optimizing compiler may however apply copy elision in the first case.  But there is no guarantee it will.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `new` variables in c++ they are allocated on the heap.  When the variables go out of scope (like when the program ends), the memory stays allocated, unless you explicitly `delete` them in your code.

You should read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/)

Comment: Ok, so is the second function equivalent to returning a pointer?